# How to set OnClickListener on a RadioButton in Android?

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I have two `RadioButton`s inside a `RadioGroup`. I want to set `OnClickListener` on those `RadioButton`s. Depending on which `RadioButton` is clicked, I want to change the text of an `EditText`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 259, accepted):

I'd think a better way is to use `RadioGroup` and set the listener on this to change and update the `View` accordingly (saves you having 2 or 3 or 4 etc listeners).

```
    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup);        
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
        }
    });
```

Comment: Wasn't working for me, Eclipse suggested I add @Override, and that fixed. Thanks

Comment: yea I would use radiogroup except it doesnt work unless its a direct parent in the xml and I cant keep it as a direct parent since this stupid radiobutton cannot be aligned to center so I had to enclose it in a linearlayout ...

Comment: you could try centering the radiobutton by putting **android:gravity="center"** in the xml under the RadioGroup tag. @RudolfRein

Comment: What do we do if the radiobutton is dynamically created, and doesnt have an id?

Answer (score 48):

Hope this will help you...

```
RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.yourFirstRadioButton);
rb.setOnClickListener(first_radio_listener);
```

and

```
OnClickListener first_radio_listener = new OnClickListener (){
 public void onClick(View v) {
   //Your Implementaions...
 }
};
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, don't forget to add a semicolon after your last curly bracket on your on click listener

Comment: Oldie but goodie. The accepted answer is leaner but doesn't handle the case of a user selecting something that's already selected. This handles it. Shame the radiogroup listener doesn't handle "setSelected" without regard for "changed".

Answer (score 30):

```
 radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
            RadioButton rb=(RadioButton)findViewById(checkedId);
            textViewChoice.setText("You Selected " + rb.getText());
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rb.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: `group` is needed in  `RadioButton rb=(RadioButton)group.findViewById(checkedId);`

Answer (score 23):

**The question was about *Detecting* which radio button is clicked, this is how you can get which button is clicked**

```
final RadioGroup radio = (RadioGroup) dialog.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        radio.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                View radioButton = radio.findViewById(checkedId);
                int index = radio.indexOfChild(radioButton);

                // Add logic here

                switch (index) {
                case 0: // first button

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected button number " + index, 500).show();
                    break;
                case 1: // secondbutton

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected button number " + index, 500).show();
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 15):

**For Kotlin** Here is added the lambda expression and Optimized the Code.

```
   radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { radioGroup, optionId ->
        run {
            when (optionId) {
                R.id.radioButton1 -> {
                    // do something when radio button 1 is selected
                }
                R.id.radioButton2 -> {
                    // do something when radio button 2 is selected
                }
                // add more cases here to handle other buttons in the your RadioGroup
            }
        }
    }
```

*Hope this will help you. Thanks!*

Comment: Helped me a lot! Thanks!

Comment: This answer always help.

Answer (score 10):

You could also add listener from XML layout: `android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"` in your `<RadioButton/>` tag.

```
<RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_pirates"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/pirates"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
```

See [Android developer SDK- Radio Buttons](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html) for details.

Answer (score 9):

Since this question isn't specific to Java, I would like to add how you can do it in **Kotlin**:

```
radio_group_id.setOnCheckedChangeListener({ radioGroup, optionId -> {
        when (optionId) {
            R.id.radio_button_1 -> {
                // do something when radio button 1 is selected
            }
            // add more cases here to handle other buttons in the RadioGroup
        }
    }
})
```

Here `radio_group_id` is the assigned `android:id` of the concerned RadioGroup. To use it this way you would need to import `kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.your_layout_name.*` in your activity's Kotlin file. Also note that in case the `radioGroup` lambda parameter is unused, it can be replaced with `_` (an underscore) since Kotlin 1.1.

Answer (score 7):

Just in case someone else was struggeling with the accepted answer:

There are different OnCheckedChangeListener-Interfaces. I added to first one to see if a CheckBox was changed.

```
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
```

vs

```
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
```

When adding the snippet from Ricky I had errors:

> The method setOnCheckedChangeListener(RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener) in the type RadioGroup is not applicable for the arguments (new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){})

Can be fixed with answer from Ali :

```
new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup);     
    radioGroup.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                        // get selected radio button from radioGroup
                        int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                        // find the radiobutton by returned id
                        radioButton =  findViewById(selectedId);
                        String slectedValue=radioButton.getText()          
        });
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation for this answer instead of simply posting code.

Comment: last line need to be: 'String slectedValue=radioButton.getText().toString()'