# How to change text in the TextView according to the RadioButton selected?

Tags: android, radio-button, textwatcher

In my application i have

- **three `Edittext`s**     and
- **one `RadioGroup`** *with* **two `RadioButton`s** and **a `TextView`**

I need to do some calculation between the values of the **three `EditText`s and display the result in the `TextView`....
I have put `TextWatcher` for the first two `EditText` so that the result is displayed simultaneously in this way..

```
  discount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                display.setText(calFinance());
            }

        });

        assetCost.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                display.setText(calFinance());
            }

        });
```

and this is the cal finance method where i am displaying the result in textview:

```
protected CharSequence calFinance() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int c1,c2,c3,c4 = 0;

    if((assetCost.getText().toString() != "") && (assetCost.getText().length() > 0)){
        c1=Integer.parseInt(assetCost.getText().toString());
        as_Asset_Cost=assetCost.getText().toString();
    }else{
        c1=0;
    }

    if(discount.getText().toString() != "" && discount.getText().length()>0){
        c3 = Integer.parseInt(discount.getText().toString());
        as_Discount=discount.getText().toString();
    }else{
        c3=0;
    }

    if(rupees.isChecked()){
        if(marginalAmt.getText().toString() !="" && marginalAmt.getText().length() > 0){
            c2=Integer.parseInt(marginalAmt.getText().toString());
            as_Margin_Amount=marginalAmt.getText().toString();

            c4 =(c1 - c2 -c3);
            ma_Finance_Amount = display.getText().toString();
                        }else{
                            marginalAmt.setError("ERROR");
                        }
    }else if(percent.isChecked()){
                if((marginalAmt.getText().toString() !="") && (marginalAmt.getText().length() > 0) && (marginalAmt.getText().length() <= 2)){

                        c2=Integer.parseInt(marginalAmt.getText().toString());
                        as_Margin_Amount=marginalAmt.getText().toString();

                        c4 = (c1*(1-(c2)/100))-c3;
                        ma_Finance_Amount = display.getText().toString();

                }   else{
                    marginalAmt.setError("ERROR");  
                }
    } else{
        c2 = 0;
        c4 = c1-c3;
        ma_Finance_Amount = display.getText().toString();
    }
    //return as_Asset_Cost;

    return String.valueOf(c4);


    }
```

now according to what radio button is selected the result in the textview should change..
as u can see in the **calfinance()** function the radio buttons rupees and percent is there for rupees the calculation is working but for percent its not...
how do i solve this issue?? I cant seem to figure out what the problem is here...

Comment: what is the text at marginalAmt?

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323778/how-to-set-on-click-listener-on-the-radio-button-in-android to set `onCheckedChangedListener` to `RadioButton`

Comment: @StinePike that is another edittext which will add to the calculations  in the textview after the radio button is clicked

Comment: yes I just wanted to know which text was shown there during you checked.. .also did you debugged the values?

Comment: @StinePike no i did not try debugging! i dont exactly know how to debug