# RadioButton inside listview

Tags: android, listview, android-radiobutton

I am using RadioGroup as a row Item inside listview. RadioGroup has 5 radio buttons and I have like 1000 rows. I am not able to mange state of radio buttons.I have tried Map for storing position and checked state. I have even tried making Class and saving checked state and radio button id with setTag() & getTag(). No luck yet. Any suggestions?

Code

Adapter class

```
package com.example.adapters;

import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.android.R;
import com.example.models.AnswerStateModel;

public class AnswerKeyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AnswerStateModel> {

    private Activity activity;
    private List<AnswerStateModel> test;
    Toast t = null;


    public AnswerKeyAdapter(Activity activity, List<AnswerStateModel> temp) {
        super(activity, R.layout.row_item_answer_key, temp);
        this.activity = activity;
        this.test = temp;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return test.size();
    }

    @Override
    public AnswerStateModel getItem(int position) {
        return test.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final int currentPosition=position;
        View view=null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(
                    R.layout.row_item_answer_key, parent,false);
            holder.lblAnswerId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblAnswerId);
            holder.rdGroup = (RadioGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.rdGroup);
            holder.btnA = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnA);
            holder.btnB = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnB);
            holder.btnC = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnC);
            holder.btnD = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnD);
            holder.btnE = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnE);
            holder.btnWhat = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnWhat);

            view.setTag(holder);
            holder.rdGroup.setTag(test.get(position));



holder.rdGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group,
                    int checkedId) {
                    AnswerStateModel model=(AnswerStateModel) holder.rdGroup.getTag();

                    switch (checkedId) {
                    case R.id.btnA:
                        model.setChecked(holder.btnA.isChecked());
                        model.setBtnId(holder.btnA.getId());
                        break;
                    case R.id.btnB:
                        model.setChecked(holder.btnB.isChecked());
                        model.setBtnId(holder.btnB.getId());
                        break;
                    case R.id.btnC:
                        model.setChecked(holder.btnC.isChecked());
                        model.setBtnId(holder.btnC.getId());
                        break;
                    case R.id.btnD:
                        model.setChecked(holder.btnD.isChecked());
                        model.setBtnId(holder.btnD.getId());
                        break;
                    case R.id.btnE:
                        model.setChecked(holder.btnE.isChecked());
                        model.setBtnId(holder.btnE.getId());
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });


        } else{

            view=convertView;
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).rdGroup.setTag(test.get(position));

        }


        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        AnswerStateModel model=(AnswerStateModel)getItem(currentPosition);

        holder.btnA.setChecked(false);
        holder.btnB.setChecked(false);
        holder.btnC.setChecked(false);
        holder.btnD.setChecked(false);
        holder.btnE.setChecked(false);

        switch (model.getBtnId()) {
        case R.id.btnA:
            holder.btnA.setChecked(test.get(position).isChecked());
            break;
        case R.id.btnB:
            holder.btnB.setChecked(test.get(position).isChecked());
            break;
        case R.id.btnC:
            holder.btnC.setChecked(test.get(position).isChecked());
            break;
        case R.id.btnD:
            holder.btnD.setChecked(test.get(position).isChecked());
            break;
        case R.id.btnE:
            holder.btnE.setChecked(test.get(position).isChecked());
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }   

        holder.lblAnswerId.setText(position+1+"");

        holder.btnWhat.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v.isSelected())
                    v.setSelected(false);
                else
                    v.setSelected(true);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView lblAnswerId;
        private RadioButton btnA;
        private RadioButton btnB;
        private RadioButton btnC;
        private RadioButton btnD;
        private RadioButton btnE;
        private RadioGroup rdGroup;
        private Button btnWhat;
    }

    void showToast(String text) {

        if (t != null)
            t.cancel();

        t = Toast.makeText(activity, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.show();
    }
}
```

Pojo class

```
package com.example.models;

public class AnswerStateModel {

    private boolean isChecked=false;
    private int btnId=0;
    private int currentPosition=0;
    private String correctAns="";
    private int btnPosition=0;



    public int getBtnPosition() {
        return btnPosition;
    }
    public void setBtnPosition(int btnPosition) {
        this.btnPosition = btnPosition;
    }
    public String getCorrectAns() {
        return correctAns;
    }
    public void setCorrectAns(String correctAns) {
        this.correctAns = correctAns;
    }
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return isChecked;
    }
    public void setChecked(boolean isChecked) {
        this.isChecked = isChecked;
    }
    public int getBtnId() {
        return btnId;
    }
    public void setBtnId(int btnId) {
        this.btnId = btnId;
    }
    public int getCurrentPosition() {
        return currentPosition;
    }
    public void setCurrentPosition(int currentPosition) {
        this.currentPosition = currentPosition;
    }



}
```

Comment: same story as CheckBox ... asked many times(store states in Adapter) ... also you wrote *I have even tried* but did not provide any of your efforts(as code)

Comment: I am adding my Code..@Selvin

Comment: @Selvin please have a look at the code I have added my code.

Comment: Few things can be better but over all you almost there,  I see only one problem ... It seems like you used wrong listener for rdGroup ... try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323778/how-to-set-on-click-listener-on-the-radio-button-in-android

Comment: Oops! old code.  I tried with onCheckChangeListener too no luck. @Selvin

Answer (score 1):

Solved it! Used [SparseIntArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseIntArray.html)

Here is the complete code.

```
/**
 * 
 */

package com.example.adapters;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.android.R;
import com.example.models.AnswerStateModel;
import com.example.utils.Config;

public class AnswerKeyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AnswerStateModel> {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<AnswerStateModel> mAnswerList;
    Toast t = null;
    private SparseIntArray mSpCheckedState=new SparseIntArray();

    public AnswerKeyAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<AnswerStateModel> mAnswerList) {
        super(activity, R.layout.row_item_answer_key, mAnswerList);
        this.activity = activity;
        this.mAnswerList = mAnswerList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mAnswerList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public AnswerStateModel getItem(int position) {
        return mAnswerList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder=null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(
                    R.layout.row_item_answer_key, parent, false);
            holder.lblAnswerId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblAnswerId);
            holder.rdGroup = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rdGroup);
            holder.btnA = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnA);
            holder.btnB = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnB);
            holder.btnC = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnC);
            holder.btnD = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnD);
            holder.btnE = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnE);
            holder.btnWhat = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnWhat);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.rdGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        holder.rdGroup.clearCheck();

        Config.error("Spars "+mSpCheckedState.get(position));
        if(mSpCheckedState.indexOfKey(position)>-1){
            holder.rdGroup.check(mSpCheckedState.get(position));
        }else{
            holder.rdGroup.clearCheck();
        }

        holder.rdGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                if(checkedId>-1){
                    mSpCheckedState.put(position, checkedId);
                }else{
                    if(mSpCheckedState.indexOfKey(position)>-1)
                        mSpCheckedState.removeAt(mSpCheckedState.indexOfKey(position));
                }               
            }
        });



        Config.error("Current Position " + position);
        holder.lblAnswerId.setText(position + 1 + "");

        holder.btnWhat.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v.isSelected())
                    v.setSelected(false);
                else
                    v.setSelected(true);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView lblAnswerId;
        private RadioButton btnA;
        private RadioButton btnB;
        private RadioButton btnC;
        private RadioButton btnD;
        private RadioButton btnE;
        private RadioGroup rdGroup;
        private Button btnWhat;
    }

    void showToast(String text) {

        if (t != null)
            t.cancel();

        t = Toast.makeText(activity, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.show();
    }
}
```