# cannot select radio button

Tags: android, radio-button

I have a RadioGroup in which I have 5 RadioButton's. Also I have a button next. On click of next button the text of radiobuttons changes. It all works fine but some of the radio buttons are not selected. This is my xml file

```
 public class SampleTestQuestionsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String totalques, timee, namee, idd;
String strServerResponse;
ProgressDialog nDialog;
ConnectionDetector cd;
Pojo pojo;
SamplePaperPojo samplePaperPojo;
RadioButton s_rb_1, s_rb_2, s_rb_3, s_rb_4, s_rb_5;
RadioGroup s_rbgrp;
private Toolbar toolbar;
TextView s_section, s_time, s_question;
Button s_submit, s_next, s_previous;

private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
private boolean timerHasStarted = false;
long startTime;
private final long interval = 1 * 1000;
final Context context = this;
ArrayList<String> al_que_title;
ArrayList<String> al_que_id;
ArrayList<String> al_ans1;
ArrayList<String> al_ans2;
ArrayList<String> al_ans3;
ArrayList<String> al_ans4;
ArrayList<String> al_ans5;
ArrayList<String> al_correct;
ArrayList<String> al_exp;
ArrayList<String> al_desc;
String submitQuestionId;
ArrayList<SamplePaperPojo> sampleTest;
RadioButton selectedRbButton;
public static int inc = 0;
String correctAns;
ArrayList<String> selectedAns;
int selectedpos;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample_test_questions);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Sample Tests");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    al_que_title = new ArrayList<String>();
    al_que_id = new ArrayList<String>();
    al_ans1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    al_ans2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    al_ans3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    al_ans4 = new ArrayList<String>();
    al_ans5 = new ArrayList<String>();
    al_correct = new ArrayList<String>();
    al_exp = new ArrayList<String>();
    al_desc = new ArrayList<String>();
    selectedAns = new ArrayList<String>();
    Intent i =getIntent();
    namee = i.getStringExtra("test_name");
    totalques = i.getStringExtra("test_ques");
    timee = i.getStringExtra("test_time");
    idd = i.getStringExtra("test_id");


    sampleTest = new ArrayList<SamplePaperPojo>();
    Log.e("test_id", ""+idd);
    Long ti = Long.valueOf(timee);
    startTime = 1000*ti;
    s_section = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sampleSectionName);
    s_time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sampleTimer);
    s_question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sampleQuestion);
    s_submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sampleSubmitAnswer);
    s_next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sampleNext);
    s_previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.samplePrevious);
    s_rbgrp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.s_rbgrp);
    s_rb_1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.SA);
    s_rb_2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.SB);
    s_rb_3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.SC);
    s_rb_4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.SD);
    s_rb_5 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.SE);

    countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
    s_time.setText(s_time.getText() + String.valueOf(startTime / 1000));
    new NetCheck().execute();

    s_next.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    s_previous.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    s_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int index_selected = s_rbgrp.indexOfChild(s_rbgrp
                    .findViewById(s_rbgrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));

            // get selected radio button from radioGroup
            int selectedId = s_rbgrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            if (selectedId==-1){
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        SampleTestQuestionsActivity.this).create();
                alertDialog.setMessage("Please select atleast one answer.");
                alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });

                alertDialog.show();
            }
            s_next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    s_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            submitQuestionId = al_que_id.get(inc).toString();
            s_rb_1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            s_rb_2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            s_rb_3.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            s_rb_4.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            s_rb_5.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            int selectedId = s_rbgrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            selectedRbButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
            selectedRbButton.setChecked(false);

            inc = inc + 1;
            s_question.setText("" + al_que_title.get(inc).toString());
            s_rb_1.setText("" + al_ans1.get(inc).toString());
            s_rb_2.setText("" + al_ans2.get(inc).toString());
            s_rb_3.setText("" + al_ans3.get(inc).toString());
            s_rb_4.setText("" + al_ans4.get(inc).toString());
            s_rb_5.setText("" + al_ans5.get(inc).toString());
            s_next.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

}

private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        nDialog = new ProgressDialog(SampleTestQuestionsActivity.this);
        nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
        nDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
        nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        nDialog.setCancelable(true);
        nDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.e("Post exec calleld", "dfds");
        nDialog.dismiss();

        s_question.setText("" + al_que_title.get(inc).toString());
        s_rb_1.setText("" + al_ans1.get(inc).toString());
        s_rb_2.setText("" + al_ans2.get(inc).toString());
        s_rb_3.setText("" + al_ans3.get(inc).toString());
        s_rb_4.setText("" + al_ans4.get(inc).toString());
        s_rb_5.setText("" + al_ans5.get(inc).toString());

        countDownTimer.start();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {

            cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

            if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(
                        new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                        SampleTestQuestionsActivity.this).create();
                                alertDialog.setMessage("Error connecting to internet.");
                                alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    }
                                });

                                alertDialog.show();
                            }
                        }
                );
            }
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httpRequest = new HttpPost(

                    "http://url");
            httpRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            SharedPreferences preff = getSharedPreferences(
                    "MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
            String userid = preff.getString("id", null);
            Log.e("Student id", "" + userid);


            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("mocktest_id", idd);
            json.put("section_id", 1);


            Log.e("JSON Object", json.toString());

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());

            se.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
            se.setContentType("application/json");

            httpRequest.setEntity(se);
            HttpResponse httpRes = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);

            java.io.InputStream inputStream = httpRes.getEntity()
                    .getContent();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            inputStream.close();
            strServerResponse = sb.toString();
            Log.e("Server Response", "" + strServerResponse.toString());
            if (strServerResponse != null) {
                try {

                    JSONArray arr1 = new JSONArray(strServerResponse);
                    JSONObject jsonObj1 = arr1.getJSONObject(0);

                    samplePaperPojo = new SamplePaperPojo();
                    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject jobjj11 = arr1
                                .getJSONObject(i);

                        String qq_id = jobjj11.optString("id");
                        String qq_title = jobjj11.optString("title");
                        String qq_des = jobjj11.optString("description");
                        String ans_a = jobjj11.optString("ans_a");
                        String ans_b = jobjj11.optString("ans_b");
                        String ans_c = jobjj11.optString("ans_c");
                        String ans_d = jobjj11.optString("ans_d");
                        String ans_e = jobjj11.optString("ans_e");
                        String right_ans = jobjj11.optString("right_ans");
                        String explanation = jobjj11.optString("explanation");

                        samplePaperPojo.setSampleQuesId(qq_id);
                        samplePaperPojo.setSampleQuesTitle(qq_title);
                        samplePaperPojo.setSampleAns1(ans_a);
                        samplePaperPojo.setSampleAns2(ans_b);
                        samplePaperPojo.setSampleAns3(ans_c);
                        samplePaperPojo.setSampleAns4(ans_d);
                        samplePaperPojo.setSampleAns5(ans_e);
                        samplePaperPojo.setSampleRightAns(right_ans);
                        samplePaperPojo.setSampleQuesDescription(qq_des);
                        samplePaperPojo.setSampleExplaination(explanation);
                        sampleTest.add(samplePaperPojo);

                        al_que_id.add(qq_id);
                        al_que_title.add(qq_title);
                        al_ans1.add(ans_a);
                        al_ans2.add(ans_b);
                        al_ans3.add(ans_c);
                        al_ans4.add(ans_d);
                        al_ans5.add(ans_e);
                        al_correct.add(right_ans);
                        al_exp.add(explanation);
                        al_desc.add(qq_des);

                    }                       

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler",
                        "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

}

 }
```

The radio button which I previously selected is not selected when the text is changed after i click on next button. Please help

Comment: What is `s_next`? Please post your complete JAVA file.

Comment: @activesince93 it is a button

Comment: @Priyanka I didn't understant this line. It all works fine but some of the radio buttons are not selected. I guess, a user can only select only one answer and you are loading the new questions and answer on next button click.

Comment: @Priyanka please update your hole java file

Comment: @RahulChaurasia The radio button which I previously selected is not selected when the text is changed after i click on next button.

Comment: @Priyanka: What do you mean `but some of the radio buttons are not selected` ?

Comment: @AmitBasliyal i have added whole java file please check

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK The radio button which I previously selected is not selected when the text is changed after i click on next button

Comment: @Priyanka try 'setOnCheckedChangeListener' in radio button  
see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323778/how-to-set-on-click-listener-on-the-radio-button-in-android

Comment: Checked `RadioButton` is not selected because you are doing this: `selectedRbButton.setChecked(false);`

Comment: @activesince93 But i have to clear the selected radio button when next data is set

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly do you want? Because in the question you are saying something else.

Comment: @activesince93 when i click on next button I want to clear the selected radio button and dislpay new data

Comment: You should do this: `s_rbgrp.clearCheck();` rather than `int selectedId = s_rbgrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            selectedRbButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
            selectedRbButton.setChecked(false);`

Comment: @activesince93 Thanks a lot.. U solved my problem

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted if it solved your problem. And please upvote it if this helped you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should replace:

```
int selectedId = s_rbgrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
selectedRbButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
selectedRbButton.setChecked(false);
```

with:

```
s_rbgrp.clearCheck();
```

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks