# How to link radio button to a new Activity in Android Studio

Tags: javascript, java, android, coding-style, android-studio-2.0

HI everyone i am new to android programming just want to open new activity by selecting one of the radio button and then clicking on the submit button, just want to know how to link new activity to radiobutton and how it will intent by clicking on submitbutton?

Comment: Check out starting an activity at official link: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

Comment: @greenapps I think it is fair to note that writing all capital letters is considered shouting. not eveyone here are native english speakers.

Comment: Check out radio button at official link: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html

Comment: you may not link an activity to radio  button but choose which activity to launch base on the radio button is chosen while clicking the button

Comment: Why do you have the `javascript` tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set On click listener on the Radio Button in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323778/how-to-set-on-click-listener-on-the-radio-button-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   private RadioGroup radioGroup;
   private RadioButton rButton1,rButton2;
   private Button next;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      radioGroup=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
      rButton1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rButton1);
      rButton2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rButton2);          
      next=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

      next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            if(rButton1.isChecked()){
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity1.class);
                startActivity(intent)
            }else if(rButton2.isChecked()){
             Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity2.class);
                startActivity(intent)
            }

         }
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement an radio button in your activity and in onClickListener of submit button get the value of radio button  selected and if it matches your requirement open your new activity using intent...

```
final RadioButton reli = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio5);
   final Button go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (reli.isChecked()) {
                Intent intents= new Intent(current_class.this, target_activity_class.class);  
                startActivity(intents);
                }
```

Comment: This could be a comment, provide a working sample in the answer

Comment: @SaravInfern, wrong. The answer does not have to have a code sample.

Comment: @VladMatvienko ok ;)