# How to use radiobutton to count something eg if the first option shows list 1 if option 2 marked show list 2?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, radio-button

I have two `RadioButton`s in `RadioGroup`. What I want: if first `RadioButton ischecked` to display method one and second `RadioButton ischecked` to dispaly method two.
How to do it?

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked (View view) {
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_button_equal_payment_principal:
            if (checked) {
            "display method PaymentPrincipal"   

            }
            break;
        case R.id.radio_button_equal_payment_total:
            if (checked) {
          "display method PaymentTotal"
            }
            break;
    }
    return ;
}
```

Comment: Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323778/how-to-set-on-click-listener-on-the-radio-button-in-android) link .may it helps you

Answer (score 0):

you can use setOnCheckedChangeListener try this :

```
itemtypeGroup
        .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
Log.d("chk", "id" + checkedId);

                if (checkedId == R.id.radio_button_equal_payment_principal) {
                    // "display method PaymentPrincipal" 
                } else if (checkedId == R.id.radio_button_equal_payment_total) {
                    //  "display method PaymentTotal"
                }

            }

        });
```

Comment: when I click radio button -->Force finishing activity

Comment: 06-06 09:37:08.385 18953-18953/? I/cm.log.servpro: [forcestop_listener][D]/  onAccessibilityEvent com.prmpteam.android.financeapp.loanactivity.LoanRootActivity, mListened = false
06-06 09:37:19.705 763-1257/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.prmpteam.android.financeapp/.loanactivity.LoanRootActivity
06-06 09:37:51.225 763-773/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{43730208 u0 com.prmpteam.android.financeapp/com.prmpteam.android.financeapp.loanactivity.LoanRootActivity}

Answer (score 0):

you can try following code:

```
radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioSex);
     radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
         @Override
         public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId) {
             switch(checkedId){
                 case R.id.radio1:
                     // do operations specific to this selection
                     break;
                 case R.id.radio2:
                     // do operations specific to this selection
                     break;

             }
         }
     });
```

Comment: when I click radio button -->Force finishing activity

Comment: 06-06 09:37:08.385 18953-18953/? I/cm.log.servpro: [forcestop_listener][D]/  onAccessibilityEvent com.prmpteam.android.financeapp.loanactivity.LoanRootActivity, mListened = false
06-06 09:37:19.705 763-1257/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.prmpteam.android.financeapp/.loanactivity.LoanRootActivity
06-06 09:37:51.225 763-773/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{43730208 u0 com.prmpteam.android.financeapp/com.prmpteam.android.financeapp.loanactivity.LoanRootActivity}

Comment: I think it is due to method that you written in onClick of radio button, please check that code .