# Radio group not setting to radio buttons Android

Tags: java, android

I am fetching data from database. Based on the value, I'm dynamically creating radio buttons. When I try to add radio group to that radio buttons, radio group is not setting up. Bcoz of that I can select many radio buttons at once.

```
attr_layout[i].addView(radioButton, lp);
attr_layout[i]` is the value for buttons which im getting. The values 
are Small, Medium and Large.
```

Here is the complete code for RadioButton.

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(mMain);
LinearLayout[] attr_layout = new LinearLayout[optionsList.size()];
                    attr_layout[i] = new LinearLayout(mMain);
                    attr_layout[i].setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

                    int attr_size = attributes.size();

                        for (int k = 0; k < attr_size; k++)
                        {
                                String price = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, AppConstants.DECIMAL_POINTS, Float.parseFloat(attributes.get(k).getAttr_price()));
                                String name_price = attributes.get(k).getAttr_name()
                                        +" ("+ mMain.getString(R.string.currency_code)
                                        +" "+ price +")";

                                if(!multiSelect.equals("1")) // This multiselect value 1 and 0 is coming from database.
                                //Based on these value, app will display checkbox or radio button
                                {
                                    final RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(mMain);
                                    radioButton.setText(name_price);
                                    radioButton.setId(i + 6);
                                    radioButton.setTextSize(12);
                                    radioButton.setTag(attributes.get(k));
                                    radioButton.setGravity(Gravity.START | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
                                    {
                                        radioButton.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START);
                                    }
                                    setTextFont(radioButton, "Museo_Slab.otf");

                                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                            1f);
                                    //lp.setMargins(10, 10, 0, 10); // llp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);


                                    RadioGroup.LayoutParams params = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                    radioGroup.setLayoutParams(params);
                                    attr_layout[i].addView(radioButton, lp);`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add radioButtons into radio group then add into layouts.

Use the code

```
radioGroup.addView(radioButton, lp);
attr_layout[i].addView(radioGroup)
```

instead of

```
attr_layout[i].addView(radioButton, lp);`
```

Comment: Let me try this one

Comment: tried with above mentioned code. Now, it allows me to select two buttons. I have 3 radio buttons. I can select 2 radio buttons. why its like that?

Comment: group means you can select only one button at the time..multiple selection not possible.if you want multi selection remove radio group..

Comment: I dont want multi selection.. i want single selection

Comment: Working.. When i select, i want it to change on click.

Comment: How can i achieve?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323778/how-to-set-on-click-listener-on-the-radio-button-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Radio group allows to check only one button at once belonging to it (if you are trying to check all buttons of a radio group).

Answer (score 0):

`radioGroup.addView(radioButton, lp);` instead of `attr_layout[i].addView(radioButton, lp);` and then put `attr_layout[i].addView(radioGroup);` after adding all `radioButton`s, i.e. outside the `for` loop.

Comment: I did what you mentioned here. Right now, i can select 2 buttons out of three. Need to make it select only one.

Comment: Check if you put all the buttons that you want exclusive of each other, inside the same RadioGroup. You probably have buttons inside different groups, which can be simultaneously selected.

Comment: Move your radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener outside the for (int k = 0; k < attr_size; k++) loop, to inside if(!multiSelect.equals("1")).