# How to get onClick event on radioButton in android

Tags: android, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I am trying to finding a way to get onClick event on radio button. I know that there is way to get a selected radio button value like this:

```
radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
```

But I have a requirement, that when user click/select radio button by touch on a screen then do some logic. So while using this way when i choose a radio button which user previous selected then  `radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener` is calling. It is little bit difficult to distinguish that who is calling `onCheckedChanged` event from code(when show previous selection) or user himself click on screen.

Can someone tell me how i can find onClick on touch event on `radioButton(not radioGroup)`

Comment: [dublicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8323909/3166697)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set OnClickListener on a RadioButton in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323778/how-to-set-onclicklistener-on-a-radiobutton-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this to get click listener to your radio button

```
RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioButton);
radioButton.setOnClickListener(radio_listener);// set listner to your radio button
```

than create a new radio_listener using below code

```
OnClickListener radio_listener = new OnClickListener (){
 public void onClick(View v) {
   //perform your action here
    if(v==radioButton){
       //perform your action here
    }
 }
};
```

Comment: I see. Can you tell me how i can get a radioButton tagId in first_radio_listener ?

Answer (score 1):

Just set onClick in XML file like this :

```
 android:onClick="Button1"
```

After this, in your java file :

```
OnClickListener yourRadiolistener = new OnClickListener (){
   public void onClick(View v) {
       //Do whatever you want to do
   }
};

RadioButton Button1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.yourFirstRadioButton);
Button1.setOnClickListener(yourRadiolistener);
```

Comment: Actually, you set the click handler programmatically and totally ignore the XML attribute in your example. Also the "Button1" variable should be lowercase. And "yourRadioListener" must be declared before it is used.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can set the click handler directly in XML:

```
<RadioGroup 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClickHandler" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClickHandler" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Your activity must then implement the onClick handler:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...

    public void onClickHandler(View view) {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.radioButton1:
                    ...
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButton2:
                    ...
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the official docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html

Answer (score 0):

you can get the id of each view that has trigered the checkchange event so get the id inside the

```
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) { if(buttonView.getId()==firstButton)
```

compare the id and apply further logic.