# Defining radio group?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to set an `OnCheckedChangeListener`on a `RadioGroup` but Android Studio gives me an error when I write it.
I used for the radio group

```
RadioGroup CheckList1 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.First_id_radio_group);
RadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener) {

}
```

When I write it as suggested (`CheckList1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(...)`), I get the following warning in Android Studio, the method gets crossed out:

[image]

Comment: It needs to be `CheckList1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){/* Your implementation goes here */});`, but variable names in Java should be camelCase, so make it `checkList1`.

Comment: I did what you told me now but there is a line on setOnCheckedChangeListener
is it normal ??

Comment: What line is there?

Comment: How can I upload the screenshot to let to check it?

Comment: Edit your question, click on the *image*-icon and paste a link or upload your local image by drag'n'drop...

Comment: @deHaar I just edit it

Comment: That *line* means the method is deprecated and you should use another option, but it should work (with certain limits that made the method become deprecated).

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup);        
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
    } 
});
```

more details: [How to set OnClickListener on a RadioButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323778/how-to-set-onclicklistener-on-a-radiobutton-in-android)